# Do you need bootstrap for @media query to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Hello I tried using a media query, everything seems ok, I actually copied it from another thread that was mark good here on stack overflow, but when I view the 'responsive layouts' web dev panel in Firefox (on every screen size I try), I see no changes!

Someone said something about adding ancestor elements to the css. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What CSS do you have inside of the media query, and what is the actual media query you used? We need to know what is supposed to happen when the screen size hits a certain point. It's easy to accidentally put a typo in your media query that stops it from working, too...

Comment: OK, thanks. For a start I tried to resize the post thumbnails:    @media screen and (max-width: 320 px) { .post-thumbnail{ width:125px; } }

Answer (score 2):

It is all about [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [**cascading/inheritance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

if you put your file.CSS after bootstrap.CSS and using the same selector as bootstrap uses then no worries, you are good to go, because cascading effect will take care of you. **This is the recommended thing to do**. You also can override it using a more specific selector.

If you don't put your file.CSS after the bootstrap, than you **always** need to be more specific then the bootstrap.CSS's selectors. **Not a good thing to do**.

You can calculate your selector's specificity [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 0):

@media screen (max-width:767px) {}
@media screen (min-width:768px)｛｝

You do not have to repeat this every single time. Just sum everything inside this media queries.

-webkit-
-moz-
-ms-
Etc..to make that work in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag in the head of your html code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bootstrap for @media query to work. You must have meta tag in the head of your html document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.